# Let $f(x,y)=\int_{0}^{x} g_1(t,0) dt+ \int _{0} ^{y} g_2(x,t) dt$ . Show that $f_x=g_1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $g_1,g_2: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ be $C^1$ and suppose $$\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial {x}}=\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial y}.$$

Let$$f(x,y)=\int_{0}^{x} g_1(t,0) dt + \int _{0} ^{y} g_2(x,t) dt.$$

Show that $$f_x=g_1$$

My Try:

$$f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)=\int_{0}^{x+h} g_1(t,0) dt + \int _{0} ^{y} g_2(x+h,t) dt-\int_{0}^{x} g_1(t,0) dt - \int _{0} ^{y} g_2(x,t) dt$$
$$=\int_{x}^{x+h}g_1(t,0)dt+\int_{0}^{y}\left(g_2(x+h,t)-g_2(x,t)\right)dt.$$
Then $$\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}=\frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}g_1(t,0)dt+\frac{1}{h}\int_{0}^{y}\left(g_2(x+h,t)-g_2(x,t)\right)dt$$
Now $g_1(t,0)$ is a function of $t$ alone. So Let $$\int g_1(t,0)dt=F(t)$$. Then we have $$\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}=\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}+\int_{0}^{y}\frac{\left(g_2(x+h,t)-g_2(x,t)\right)}{h}dt$$

Taking limit on both sides as $h \to 0$, we get

$$f_x=F'(x)+\int_{0}^{y}\frac{\partial g_2(x,t)}{\partial x}dt=g_1(t,0)+\int_{0}^{y}\frac{\partial g_1(x,t)}{\partial t}dt=g_1(t,0)+g_1(x,y)-g_1(x,0)=g_1$$

Is this alright??

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: The tricky bit (from a rigorous real analysis point of view) is showing that $\int_0^y \frac{g(x+h,t) - g(x,t)}h \, dt \to \int_0^y \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,t) \, dt$.  Are you allowed to quote that?

Comment: I am allowed to do that. But to show that rigorously I have to use continuity of partial derivatives I guess and mean value theorem

Comment: Then the proof looks fine to me.

Comment: If I am to prove the thing u mentioned I am to use mean value theorem and continuity of partial derivatives ?? Thanks anyways!!

Comment: I don't immediately see how to do it.  What theorems do you have about when $\int_a^b f_n(x) \, dx \to \int_a^b f(x) \, dx$?